# Equivalent codes from PHP and .net gives different returns

Tags: php, asp.net, vb.net

I have two functions that should returns same value. The functions decode a text in base 64.

Code in PHP

```
$kc = 'sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7';
function decodeBase64($data){
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Code in vb.net

```
Dim kc As String = "sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7"
Function DecodeBase64(data As String) As String
    Dim decodedBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(data)
    Return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedBytes)
End Function
```

Return of PHP is

```
��ǎ�\u000e\u0005�\u000b�� �,�>l�O;�\u0002{
```

Return of .NEt is

```
��ǎ���� �,�>l�O;�{
```

PHP code is right. could anyone tell me what is wrong with the .Net equivalent code?

Comment: Guess it has something to do with the character encoding.

Comment: the raw bytes are identical. they're just being displayed differently.

Comment: Can you show us the full code of these functions (especially the PHP one) ?